# Designing an optimization on throughput of EF.Core application

Tags: optimization, entity-framework, efcore

I am looking for feedback on a design problem I encountered when processing batches of db entries. The issue at hand is efficiency and throughput of an application.

The application looks like this simple pseudo-code

```csharp
// The loop is done outside of the application by some sort of orchestration
while (true){

    void Main(){

        // Note: All 1000 entries are tracked by EF.core here
        IQueryable<MyDbObject> data = DbContext.MyDbObjectSet.Take(1000);

        await Update_All_Data_Records_Async(data);

        DbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

### Structure

- `Main` is the entire executable
- The outer loop is an orchestrator that simply starts the program, after it completes, over and over
- `Update_All_Data_Records_Async` modifies between 1 and N tasks concurrently
- `Update_All_Data_Records_Async` is network IO bound per `MyDbObject`
- `DbContext.SaveChanges();` must not be called while `data` is modified concurrently
- `Update_All_Data_Records_Async` will *always* eventually return, having modified [0..N] `MyDbObject`s

### Data

- A batch of N (=1000) MyDbObject are queried from the DB
- Currently EF tracks all N elements for changes (change tracking is enabled)
- After `Update_All_Data_Records_Async` ran on the entire batch, the batch is written back to the DB.
- The EF change-tracker decides which elements to write back
- This setup works lock-free

### Problem

- Regardless of size N, the batch of `MyDbObject` will *always* contain a distribution of durations, where some `MyDbObject` will be `quick`, `medium` and `slow` to process. (Always all three!)
- The duration of `quick`, `medium` and `slow` vary with every call to `Main`
- Therefore a fixed `Update_All_Data_Records_Async` time period will be either too short or too long
- It is not possible to cluster `MyDbObject` beforehand by duration (it is not known)
- The entire batch of N (=1000) will be updated, after even the slowest element has completed
- The throughput of this application is determined and dragged down by tasks of the `slow` category.

### How this program behaves

- It queries N `MyDbObject` and starts processing them.
- `Update_All_Data_Records_Async` balances execution for maximum throughput of each `data` by scaling the amount of concurrent tasks
- Eventually a large percentage of tasks will complete fairly fast.
- A small percentage will take very long resulting in a drop in throughput
- About >90% of the tasks are finished early but not written to DB because some tasks stall completion of `Update_All_Data_Records_Async`
- The total throughput of a run of `Main` drops massively

Basically my aim is to increase throughput of individual runs but also to ensure that eventually also `slow` tasks gets processed (instead of always "detect and discard" them).

I have ideas on how to redesign this but I would love to get some peer feedback from different angles on this issue and maybe find even simpler solutions to this. Maybe also with some `EF.core` expertise since this is a constraint of the existing solution. Everything else is re-designable, even the outside loop of the orchestrator.

Comment: given that you can change N, whats the problem with writing the fast updates before the slow ones finish? Is it just because EF saves everything when you call savechanges?

Comment: I couldnt tell you the syntax off the top of my head, but im pretty sure you can get the list as a detached set, and then call a batch update on _only_ completed rows periodically. Which will mean you can change your loop to a queue setup where you continually get new records as you complete them

Comment: @Ewan regardless of size of N, some elements will eventually be slow, dragging the throughput down.

Comment: @Ewan I am aware of detaching the entries and update only completed one, but this involves book keeping of selected entries (most likely inside the DB) and a lot of other changes. Your recommendation is indeed one possible solution I was aware but I don't know, what else I am currently not knowing, therefore this question :)